# Convergence of Redefined Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

So I was solving some series related problems when I got stuck at the end of this one. Here it goes.

Let $a_n$ be a sequence of positive real numbers such that $a_n\to c$, for some $c\in\mathbb{R}$. Study the convergence of the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{a_n}{a_{n-1}+a_{n+1}}$$

1. Suppose $c>0$, then $\lim\dfrac{a_n}{a_{n-1}+a_{n+1}}=\dfrac{1}{2}$, so in this case the series diverges.
2. Suppose $c=0$, then

   - If $\sum a_n=\infty$ then, for $n$ sufficiently large $a_{n-1}+a_{n+1}<1$, so $a_n<\dfrac{a_n}{a_{n-1}+a_{n+1}}$, hence the series diverges.
   - If $\sum a_n<\infty$ (here is where I'm stuck)

I'm guessing it still fails but just can't see it right away. Thanks!

Comment: Don't swing for the fences.  Instead, take the **baby steps** of trying various pertinent sample sequences, see what happens, and try to spot a pattern.  Although you have formatted the question nicely (re mathJax), you actually **have shown no work.**  Once you have (for example) spent 30 minutes to an hour taking the baby steps, please edit your query to show your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If  $a_n=\dfrac{1}{2^n}$, then $\sum \dfrac{a_n}{a_{n-1}+a_{n+1}}$ diverges.

If  $a_n=\dfrac{1}{2^{n^2}}$, then $\sum \dfrac{a_n}{a_{n-1}+a_{n+1}}$ converges.

So, we can find $(a_n)$ for which $\sum \dfrac{a_n}{a_{n-1}+a_{n+1}}$ converges and other sequences $(a_n)$ for which $\sum \dfrac{a_n}{a_{n-1}+a_{n+1}}$ diverges. The convergence of $\sum a_n$ is a necessary (but not sufficient) condition for the convergence of $\sum \dfrac{a_n}{a_{n-1}+a_{n+1}}$.

Can we do better ? Yes.

We can show that $\sum \dfrac{a_n}{a_{n-1}+a_{n+1}}$ converges if and only if $\sum \dfrac{a_{n}}{a_{n-1}}$ converges.

Comment: I was so close haha, this is what I was looking for, thanks!